# CheckBoxPreference dependency not found error

Tags: android, dependencies

I have this CheckBoxPreference

```
CheckBoxPreference sendToEmailPref = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
sendToEmailPref.setTitle("Send To Email");
sendToEmailPref.setDependency("emailList");
```

I want to set its dependency on a key "emailList" 
emailList is a custom build preference which stores the email addressees as a String.

However, I am getting this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dependency not found.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final CheckBoxPreference sendImageToEmail = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("send_image_to_email");
listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key.equals("emailList")) {
            String emails = sharedPreferences
                    .getString("emailList", "");
            if (emails.equals("")) {
                sendImageToEmail.setChecked(false);
```

I used a `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` to do it.

Answer (score 10):

you should call setDependency after you have finished calling addPreference
It works for me well!

Answer (score 4):

Get your .setDependency() to just after setPreferenceScreen() in your onCreate. It should work.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setPreferenceScreen(createPreferenceHierarchy());
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("_key_of_depend_to_").setDependency("emailList");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added a preference with a "emailList" key *before* you add the dependency to your `CheckBoxPreference`. I've had something like below working for me (in my `PreferenceFragment`).

```
Context context = getActivity();

PreferenceScreen root = getPreferenceManager.createPreferenceScreen(context);
setPreferenceScreen(root);

CustomPreference customPref = new CustomPreference(context);
customPref.setTitle("My Custom Preference");
customPref.setKey("emailList");

root.addPreference(customPref);

CheckBoxPreference sendToEmailPref = new CheckBoxPreference(context);
sendToEmailPref.setTitle("Send To Email");

root.addPreference(sendToEmailPref);

sendToEmailPref.setDependency("emailList");
```

Comment: This is basically a clarification of ys126's answers.

Answer (score 0):

you should write `sendToEmailPref.setDependency("emailList")` after `setPreferenceScreen(yourScreen)`
assume i write:

```
 override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        val context = preferenceManager.context
        val screen = preferenceManager.createPreferenceScreen(context)
        ...
```

and have a switchPreference :

```
val mySwitchPreference = SwitchPreference(context)
mySwitchPreference.key = "my_switch_preference"
screen.addPreference(mySwitchPreference )
...
```

and have a SeekBarPreference that i want to be dependent on "mySwitchPreference".
if switch is "ON" then seekbar is enabled else seekbar is disabled:

```
val mySeekBarPreference = SeekBarPreference(context)
mySeekBarPreference.key = "my_seekbar_preference"
screen.addPreference(mySeekBarPreference)
...



preferenceScreen = screen
mySeekBarPreference.dependency = mySwitchPreference.key
```

if you do try to set dependency for seekBarPrefernece, before setting
screen as PreferenceScreen, it gives you this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dependency "my_switch_preference" not found for preference "my_seekbar_preference"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following code:-

```
private static final String PARENT_CHECKBOX_PREFERENCE = "parent_checkbox_preference";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PreferenceScreen root = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);
        setPreferenceScreen(root);
        populatePreferenceHierarchy(root);
    }

private void populatePreferenceHierarchy(PreferenceScreen pScreenRoot) {
        // Preference attributes
        PreferenceCategory prefAttrsCat = new PreferenceCategory(this);
        prefAttrsCat.setTitle("preference_attributes");
        pScreenRoot.addPreference(prefAttrsCat);

        // Visual parent toggle preference
        CheckBoxPreference parentCheckBoxPref = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
        parentCheckBoxPref.setKey(PARENT_CHECKBOX_PREFERENCE);
        parentCheckBoxPref.setTitle("title_parent_preference");
        parentCheckBoxPref.setSummary("summary_parent_preference");
        prefAttrsCat.addPreference(parentCheckBoxPref);


        // Visual child toggle preference
        // See res/values/attrs.xml for the <declare-styleable> that defines TogglePrefAttrs.
        TypedArray typeA = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.TogglePrefAttrs);
        CheckBoxPreference childCheckBoxPref = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
        childCheckBoxPref.setKey("child_checkbox_preference");
        childCheckBoxPref.setTitle("title_child_preference");
        childCheckBoxPref.setSummary("summary_child_preference");
        childCheckBoxPref.setLayoutResource(typeA.getResourceId(R.styleable.TogglePrefAttrs_android_preferenceLayoutChild, 0));
        prefAttrsCat.addPreference(childCheckBoxPref);
        childCheckBoxPref.setDependency(PARENT_CHECKBOX_PREFERENCE);

        typeA.recycle();
}
```